# Confusing message on "Hot questions" widget

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, hot-questions, android-app-widgets

I have the Stack Exchange "Hot Questions" widget that is part of the SE Android app on my phone's home screen.

Today I had my phone in flight mode for a few hours, which made the following text appear on the widget:

[image: "Unable to load hot question, check your internet connection"]

After I had turned on WiFi again, the widget kept showing this message for a while (I guess it just synchs every few minutes, but that's not the problem here).

As I am the average dumb user, I expected that message to be the title of a hot question and even tapped it because I wanted to know the background of such a question title. This is what confused me:

- the message had the same style as a question title (font, size, color)
- on the left, there still was the "Community Building" icon from the last available hot question
- I did not expect an error message, since I had left flight mode some minutes earlier

Is it possible that this behavior will be changed with the next update? Using a smaller font size and maybe another color (black?) would clearly mark messages as messages, I think. Also, the icon should be hidden in such a case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

I changed the text color to not look like a link, removed the background color, and made it so tapping doesn't open the last displayed question.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: Good news! I never fell for it again but this still bugged me every time I saw it.